# MyBatis - JUnit test shows 'out of memory'

Tags: java, spring, junit, out-of-memory, mybatis

I am doing JUnit test with spring 3.1.1 and MyBatis.
I made a resultMap and put a customized typeHandler to handling null Value.

My Map looks like below :

```
<resultMap type="map" id="program">
    <result property="serviceId"        column="ID_SVC"                 typeHandler="StringHandler"/>
    <result property="programId"        column="ID_EVENT"               typeHandler="StringHandler"/>
    <result property="programName"      column="NM_TITLE"               typeHandler="StringHandler"/>
    <result property="directorName"     column="NM_DIRECTOR"            typeHandler="StringHandler"/>
    <result property="actorName"        column="NM_ACT"                 typeHandler="StringHandler"/>
    <result property="ratingCd"         column="CD_RATING"              typeHandler="StringHandler"/>
    <result property="synopsis"         column="NM_SYNOP"               typeHandler="StringHandler"/>
    <result property="img"              column="IMG"                    typeHandler="StringHandler"/>
    <result property="startTime"        column="DT_EVNT_START"/>
    <result property="endTime"          column="DT_EVNT_END"/>
</resultMap>
```

there is no doubt that my "StringHandler" works fine since my other queries which use same handler works without error.

but somehow when I do this Query I got message `"Out of memory"`.

```
DAOTest.testCacheAllProg
testCacheAllProg(com.test.dao.DAOTest)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:753)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:385)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.UnknownTypeHandler.resolveTypeHandler(UnknownTypeHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.UnknownTypeHandler.getNullableResult(UnknownTypeHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:55)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getPropertyMappingValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:390)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.applyPropertyMappings(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:364)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:338)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:291)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:266)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:236)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:150)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:60)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:73)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:60)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:137)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:96)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:108)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:358)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:198)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:119)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getAllProg(Unknown Source)
```

I do not know why this happens. Could you find any clues from this messages?
It works with same query and same resultMap in iBatis.(When I ran this query in SQLDeveloper, it took 23 seconds. I know it has some problem but at it also works fine)

Thanks for helping me :D

P.S. 
I am sorry that I can not open my queries. It has some security problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like MyBatis is trying to turn an entire result set into a HashMap.  And there are other hints that the resultset is "rather large".

I'm not sure what the solution is, but the alternatives would include:

- increase the heap size (though that may just be putting off the problem),
- changing the query so that there are fewer results in the resultset
- (somehow) changing the way that your application is processing the results so that it doesn't need to load them into a huge HashMap ...

Comment: Thanks^^b Your first and second suggestion is not available because I do not have authority to modify that. I can not understand why MyBatis takes more memories than iBatis to handle same data:<

Comment: In Addition, there is no chance to interfere. I got only xml file which specifies queries and an Interface. What I have done is just make a JUnit Test and @Inject Interface and run. So I need something else can managing between Interface and xml.

Comment: *"I can not understand why MyBatis takes more memories than iBatis to handle same data"* - Shrug,  Different implementation, different behaviour.  *"In Addition, there is no chance to interfere."*  - Well it sounds like you just need to report to ... whoever ... that the JUnit test has found a problem with memory usage that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that I needed.
As Stephen said its main cause is HashMap.
When MyBatis pull data from DB, it works as batch.

So I need to handling by row and free memory.
Here is what I have done to solve this.

- made an Implemented class which implements ibatis.ResultHandler.
- add a parameter to method in mapper interface.

For instance.

```
public class RowHandler implements ResultHandler {
  @Override
  public void handleResult(Resultcontext context){
    //I am not sure, but I think I do not have to do anything here.
    //I guess it automatically handle by row by itself.
  }
}
```

then your Mapper interface method :

```
public Map<String, Object> getProgram(Map<String, Object> param, ResultHandler rowHandler) throws Exception
```

Finally, when you call the method, simply put Customized ResultHandler(In this case, `RowHandler`) as second parameter.

I am done with my problem, but knowledge about MyBatis ResultHandler. So you add some comment under here if I were wrong.

Thanks !